# How to order only one element present in an Array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to order *only one* element present in a `Array` resulting from executing a `ActiveRecord::Relation`. That is, I have an `ActiveRecord::Relation` that returns the following `Array`:

```
[
  #<Article id: 1, title: "Sample title 1", content: "Sample content 1">,
  #<Article id: 2, title: "Sample title 2", content: "Sample content 2">,
  #<Article id: 3, title: "Sample title 3", content: "Sample content 3">,
  #<Article id: 4, title: "Sample title 4", content: "Sample content 4">,
  #<Article id: 5, title: "Sample title 5", content: "Sample content 5">,
  ...
]
```

I would like to "put" / "order" the `Article` object with `id` 4 and `title` "Sample title 4" to the *first position* in the `Array` so to make it possible to output that related object data as the first element in my view files.

How it is possible to  make that?

Comment: You can assign weights to articles and sort by that when retrieving. so, in your case, id=4 will be the "heaviest" one and will come first.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev - Could you be more explicit (maybe with an example)?

Comment: you could use e.g. the acts_as_list-gem (https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) to help you weighting your articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `order` to this, it will generate sql from your order, which evaluates to a true or fals condition, and this brings your desired elements first:

```
Article.order('id = 4, title = "Sample title 4"')
```

Quite hardcoded, but it works.

Comment: *BTW*: I could use also `order(:id => 4)`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it should be

```
Article.order("id = 4 DESC")
```

Comment: What exactly makes your code? That is, it orders only the article record with `id = 4` (putting that record to the first position) or it has some effect also on ordering other records?